# How to get pdf page number in aws textract

Tags: amazon-textract

I am using AWS TETXRACT API. I am looking for a way to get pdf page number also along with text. How can we capture PDF meta data.

Using get_document_text_detection looked for all options to get the metadata but quiet unsuccessful. Please suggest how to get pdf metadata which is page number.  does responce pages capture this information.